# Get data from website with login context and send it to another website

Tags: javascript, rest

I am using a third party API to retrieve user data: `api.thirdparty.com/activity=myuser`. The following response is returned if the authenticated user is the same as the queried user.

```
{
  "activity": {
    "total": 123,
    "posts": 100,
    "comments": 20,
    "likes": 3,
  }
}
```

However if the request sender is unauthenticated or is not the queried user, it will return the following response instead:

```
{
  "activity": {
    "total": 123
  }
}
```

What I want is to get the more detailed response and post it to my own backend: `api.mywebsite.com/post`. Obviously, I could set up a form on my frontend `mywebsite.com` and login the user on my backend to retrieve the desired response. However, I don't want the responsibility of handling passwords from a third party website. Instead, I want the following flow:

1. Instruct user to login on `thirdparty.com`.
2. User will click a button on `mywebsite.com` and give whatever permissions are required.
3. Button will execute some Javascript to retrieve data from `thirdparty.com`.